How to import a row from a sheet when text matches one column
First question on here, so bear with me. I'm trying to import a row of data that corresponds with the first column after matching it with the text in one sheet.
Here's the situation. I have a list of camps and each of them has specific needs. That list and the camp needs are in one sheet, and I would love to get it to show up in the form of our schedule. So each week some camps will be offered and their titles are listed, now I'd like to import the camp needs for only those titles.
Here is an example sheet where the first sheet, "Schedule" is where I want data to show up, and the second sheet "Specifics" is where the list of camp data is.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IfBUloRducq0E3Giq0mAMw8svwrkSzLoqevvBPK6oJ8/edit?usp=sharing
I've played around with matching text and importing, both from a sheet in the same workbook and with it existing in a separate workbook. I'm struggling to get the text to match AND import only the row that corresponds with that match. I'll be honest that I'm a pretty novice spreadsheet user so I welcome any thoughts or explanation you can give!


You can use xlookup to retrieve the matching info with camp title being the common factor. Use this single formula in Cell_B3
=map(A3:A,lambda(Σ,xlookup(Σ,Specifics!A:A,Specifics!B:F,)))



use simple vlookup:
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, Specifics!$A:$F, {2,3,4,5,6}, )))




I used the first answer posted with xlookup but thank you for your answer - good to know another way to accomplish this!
